# Downloading source jars in sbt?

Tags: sbt

I pulled down the sources and build/published it locally.  I want to debug into sources jars. When I publish it locally, I clearly see it also publishes source jars.

```
[info]  published securesocial-testkit_2.10 to local\ws.securesocial\securesocial-testkit_2.10\master-SNAPSHOT\srcs\securesocial-testkit_2.10-sources.jar
```

I don't know how to reference this jar.

Changing `"ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT"` to `"ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT-sources"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add `withSources()` to the dependency definition.

From [Download Sources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#download-sources) in the official documentation of sbt:

> Downloading source and API documentation jars is usually handled by an
>   IDE plugin. These plugins use the updateClassifiers and
>   updateSbtClassifiers tasks, which produce an Update Report referencing
>   these jars.
>
> To have sbt download the dependency's sources without using an IDE
>   plugin, add `withSources()` to the dependency definition. For API jars,
>   add `withJavadoc()`. For example:
>
> ```
> libraryDependencies += "org.apache.felix" % "org.apache.felix.framework" % "1.8.0" withSources() withJavadoc()
> ```
>
> Note that this is not transitive. Use the `update-*classifiers` tasks
>   for that.

Answer (score 26):

You can also run `sbt update-classifiers` to download sources and javadoc jars for all project dependencies at once

For sbt 1.0, command is `sbt updateClassifiers`

Comment: Update: Moot point.  The Ensime SBT plugin *does* acquire sources when they are available.  Warnings are given for Maven resources without sources available.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it worked better with

```
sbt ';reload plugins; updateClassifiers'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the eclipse ide backed with the sbt eclipse plugin, the sbt command is:

```
eclipse with-source=true
```